# Unity Error after installation on ubuntu 14.4

Tags: unity, gui, synaptic

No application opens after installing such as synaptic, vlc, wine, etc. please help as I think there is some problem with the gui. Is it got to something with the unity?

Comment: Have you tried running these apps from Terminal?

Comment: yes i have tried. everything gets installed but when I try to open any application nothing opens up. Also on terminal when i entered unity i got this error. ERROR 40 unity.glib.dbus.server GLib Server.cpp:524 DBus name list 'com.canonical.Unity

Comment: ERROR 2014-04-21 17:00:49 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:524 DBus name lost 'org.gnome.Shell'
ERROR 2014-04-21 17:00:49 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:524 DBus name lost 'com.canonical.Unity'